# Getting "System.QueryException: unexpected token: ORDER" in VFPage

Tags: apex

```
public class OrderExtension {

    public Order orderRecord {get;set;}
    public List<OrderItem> orderItemList {get;set;}
    public String selectedFamily {get;set;}
    public List<chartHelper.chartData> pieData {get;set;}
    public Decimal total {get;set;}

    public Map<Id,OrderItem> orderItemMap;
    ApexPages.StandardSetController standardSetController;

    public OrderExtension(ApexPages.StandardController standardController){
        orderRecord = (Order)standardController.getRecord();
        orderItemMap = new Map<Id,OrderItem>();
        selectedFamily = Constants.SELECT_ONE;
        if ( orderRecord.Id != null ){
            orderRecord = queryOrderRecord(orderRecord.Id);
        }

        resetSsc();
        total = 0;

        for (OrderItem oi : orderRecord.OrderItems) {
            orderItemMap.put(oi.Product2Id, oi);
            if (oi.Quantity > 0) {
                if (null == pieData) {
                    pieData = new List<ChartHelper.ChartData>();
                }
                pieData.add(new chartHelper.ChartData(oi.Product2.Name, oi.Quantity * oi.UnitPrice));
                total += oi.UnitPrice * oi.Quantity;
            }
        }
        PopulateOrderItems();
    }

    void resetSsc() {
        String query = 'SELECT Name, Product2.Family, Product2.Name, Product2Id, UnitPrice, Product2.Quantity_Remaining__c'
                     + '  FROM PricebookEntry WHERE IsActive = TRUE LIMIT 15';

        if (selectedFamily != null && selectedFamily != Constants.SELECT_ONE) {
            query += ' AND Product2.Family = \'' + selectedFamily + '\'';
        }
        query += ' ORDER BY Name';
        IF(standardSetController == null ){
            standardSetController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(query));
            standardSetController.setPageSize(Constants.DEFAULT_ROWS);
        }
        
    }
    private void setStandardSetController() {
        if (this.selectedFamily != Constants.SELECT_ONE && this.selectedFamily != null) {
            this.standardSetController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id,
                            Product2.Name,Product2.Family,Product2Id,UnitPrice,Product2.Quantity_Remaining__c FROM PricebookEntry
                    WHERE Product2.IsActive = true AND Product2.Family =: this.selectedFamily]));
        } else {
            this.standardSetController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id,Product2.Name,Product2.Family,
                            Product2Id,UnitPrice,Product2.Quantity_Remaining__c FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Product2.IsActive = true]));
        }

        this.standardSetController.setPageSize(Constants.DEFAULT_ROWS);
    }
    void PopulateOrderItems() {
        orderItemList = new List<OrderItem>();
        for (SObject obj : standardSetController.getRecords()) {
            PricebookEntry pbe = (PricebookEntry)obj;

            if (orderItemMap.containsKey(pbe.Product2Id)) {
                orderItemList.add(orderItemMap.get(pbe.Product2Id));
            } else {
                orderItemList.add(new OrderItem(
                    PricebookEntryId=pbe.Id,
                    Product2Id=pbe.Product2Id,
                    UnitPrice=pbe.UnitPrice,
                    Quantity=0,
                    Product2=pbe.Product2
                ));
            }
        }
    }
    public void OnFieldChange(){
        //ToDo: Implement logic to store the values changed on the page
        for (OrderItem oi : orderItemList) {
            orderItemMap.put(oi.Product2Id, oi);
        }

        //      and populate pieData
        pieData = null;
        total = 0;
        for (OrderItem oi : orderItemMap.values()) {
            if (oi.Quantity > 0) {
                if (null == pieData) {
                    pieData = new List<chartHelper.ChartData>();
                }
                pieData.add(new chartHelper.ChartData(oi.Product2.Name, oi.Quantity * oi.UnitPrice));
                //      and populate total
                total += oi.UnitPrice * oi.Quantity;
            }

        }

    }
    public void SelectFamily(){
        //ToDo: Implement logic to filter based on the selected product family
        resetSsc();
        PopulateOrderItems();
    }
    public void Save(){
        //ToDo: Implement logic to save the Order and populated OrderItems
        System.Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
        try {
            if (null == orderRecord.Pricebook2Id) {
                orderRecord.Pricebook2Id = Constants.STANDARD_PRICEBOOK_ID;
            }
            upsert orderRecord;

            List<OrderItem> orderItemsToUpsert = new List<OrderItem>();
            List<OrderItem> orderItemsToDelete = new List<OrderItem>();
            for (OrderItem oi : orderItemMap.values()) {
                if (oi.Quantity > 0) {
                    if (null == oi.OrderId) {
                        oi.OrderId = orderRecord.Id;
                    }
                    orderItemsToUpsert.add(oi);
                } else if (oi.Id != null) {
                    orderItemsToDelete.add(oi);
                }
            }

            upsert orderItemsToUpsert;
            delete orderItemsToDelete;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Database.rollback(sp);
            apexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,Constants.ERROR_MESSAGE));
        }
    }
    public void First(){
        standardSetController.first();
        PopulateOrderItems();
    }
    public void Next(){
        standardSetController.next();
        PopulateOrderItems();
    }
    public void Previous(){
        standardSetController.previous();
        PopulateOrderItems();
    }
    public void Last(){
        standardSetController.last();
        PopulateOrderItems();
    }
    public Boolean GetHasPrevious(){
        return standardSetController.getHasPrevious();
    }
    public Boolean GetHasNext(){
        return standardSetController.getHasNext();
    }
    public Integer GetTotalPages(){
        Integer totalPages = (Integer)Math.ceil(standardSetController.getResultSize() / (Decimal)Constants.DEFAULT_ROWS);
        System.debug('############ totalPages: ' + totalPages);
        return totalPages;
    }
    public Integer GetPageNumber(){
        return standardSetController.getPageNumber();
    }
    public List<SelectOption> GetFamilyOptions() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>{
            new SelectOption(Constants.SELECT_ONE, Constants.SELECT_ONE)
        };
        for (Schema.PicklistEntry ple : Constants.PRODUCT_FAMILY) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(ple.getValue(), ple.getLabel()));
        }
        return options;
    }
  
    public static Order QueryOrderRecord(Id orderId){
            return [SELECT Id, AccountId, EffectiveDate, Name, Status, Pricebook2Id,
                    (SELECT Id, OrderId, Quantity, UnitPrice, PricebookEntryId, Product2Id,
                         Product2.Name, Product2.Family, Product2.Quantity_Remaining__c
                    FROM OrderItems where PricebookEntry.isActive = true AND Order.Id =: OrderId) From Order];
    }
}
```

---

Visualforce code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Order" extensions="OrderExtension" >
    <apex:sectionHeader title="{!$ObjectType.Order.Label} Edit" subtitle="{!IF(Order.Id == null,'New '+$ObjectType.Order.Label,Order.Name)}" />
    <apex:form id="form" >
        <apex:pageMessages id="pageMessages" />
        <apex:pageBlock title="Order Details" mode="Edit">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!orderRecord.AccountId}" required="true" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!orderRecord.Name}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!orderRecord.EffectiveDate}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!orderRecord.Status}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:actionRegion >
            <apex:pageBlock title="Summary" id="summary" >
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" >
                    <apex:pageMessage severity="Info" summary="No Products have been selected" rendered="{!pieData == null}" />
                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!pieData != null}" >
                        <apex:chart height="250" width="350" data="{!pieData}" >
                            <apex:pieSeries dataField="val" labelField="name"/>
                            <apex:legend position="right"/>
                        </apex:chart>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Order.Fields.TotalAmount.label}" />
                        <apex:outputText value="{0,number,$0.00}" id="total" ><apex:param value="{!total}" /></apex:outputText>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlock title="{!$ObjectType.Product2.Label}" id="orderItemTable" >
                <apex:pageBlockSection >
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Product2.Fields.Family.label}" />
                        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedFamily}" size="1" >
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!familyOptions}" />
                            <apex:actionSupport action="{!selectFamily}" event="onchange" reRender="pageMessages, pagination, orderItemTable" />
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!orderItemList}" var="o" >
                    <apex:column headerValue="Qty">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!o.Quantity}" >
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!onFieldChange}" reRender="pageMessages, summary" />
                        </apex:inputField>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Product2.Fields.Family.label}">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!o.Product2.Family}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.OrderItem.Fields.Product2Id.label}" >
                        <apex:outputField value="{!o.Product2Id}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.OrderItem.Fields.UnitPrice.label}">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!o.UnitPrice}" >
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!onFieldChange}" reRender="pageMessages, summary" />
                        </apex:inputField>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Product2.Fields.Quantity_Remaining__c.label}" >
                        <apex:outputField value="{!o.Product2.Quantity_Remaining__c}" />
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>
            <center>
                <apex:panelGrid id="pagination" columns="9" >
                <apex:commandButton value="<< First" disabled="{!hasPrevious==false}" action="{!first}" reRender="pageMessages, pagination, orderItemTable" />
                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                <apex:commandButton value="< Previous" disabled="{!hasPrevious==false}" action="{!previous}" reRender="pageMessages, pagination, orderItemTable" />
                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                <span>Page {!pageNumber} of {!totalPages}</span>
                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                <apex:commandButton value="Next >" disabled="{!hasNext==false}" action="{!next}" reRender="pageMessages, pagination, orderItemTable" />
                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                <apex:commandButton value="Last >>" disabled="{!hasNext==false}" action="{!last}" reRender="pageMessages, pagination, orderItemTable" />
                </apex:panelGrid>
            </center>
        </apex:actionRegion>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Please help me to solve the queryexception: Order.Thanks in advance
Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong:
There was an unexpected error in your org which is preventing this assessment check from completing: System.QueryException: unexpected token: ORDER

Comment: Too much code dumped without any exception stacktrace. Can you please show specific snippet where the exception is coming.Also I think `QueryOrderRecord` will return a `List<Order>`. As there might not be any record being returned your code might be throwing this `System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject`, as it wont be able to assign any thing to the return `Order`.

Comment: Sir I think am getting error while calling the SOQL Query as per am using suqueries to retrieve order as well as related orderitems

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace?

Comment: public static Order QueryOrderRecord(Id orderId){
            return [SELECT Id, AccountId, EffectiveDate, Name, Status, Pricebook2Id,
                    (SELECT Id, OrderId, Quantity, UnitPrice, PricebookEntryId, Product2Id,
                         Product2.Name, Product2.Family, Product2.Quantity_Remaining__c
                    FROM OrderItems where PricebookEntry.isActive = true AND Order.Id =: OrderId) From Order];
    }   I tink am getting in this part

Comment: I meant error stacktrace. Like copy paste the full exception bu editing your question.

Comment: Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong:
There was an unexpected error in your org which is preventing this assessment check from completing: System.QueryException: unexpected token: ORDER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are completing a trailhead challenge and as per the exception your dynamic query is not correct.

Your `LIMIT` should be at the end of the query.

Like this:

```
String query = 'SELECT Name, Product2.Family, Product2.Name, Product2Id, UnitPrice, Product2.Quantity_Remaining__c'
    + '  FROM PricebookEntry WHERE IsActive = TRUE';
if (selectedFamily != null && selectedFamily != Constants.SELECT_ONE) {
        query += ' AND Product2.Family = \'' + selectedFamily + '\'';
}
query += ' ORDER BY Name LIMIT 15';
```

Comment: As I changed the code am getting an error :   Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong:
Ensure that values are preserved during pagination.

Comment: I dont think that is a apex exception , that might have something to do with your environment data or setup. As I am not doing that same trailhead challenge, I wont be able to help you to resolve `Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: Ensure that values are preserved during pagination`

Comment: Ok till this thanks for your help.